# Prove that $\sum_{cyc}(1-x)^2\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{z^2(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}{(xy+z)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $x,y,z>0$. Show that
> $$\sum_{cyc}(1-x)^2\ge \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{z^2(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}{(xy+z)^2}.$$

**Source**: In a blog entry posted in 2013, it was said that this problem was proposed by Dongyi Wei (full marks both at 50th IMO 2009 and 49th IMO 2008) and was solved by Zipei Nie (full marks at 51st IMO 2010).

Here's what I have done. The expression
$$\sum_{cyc}(1-x)\left((1-x)-\dfrac{z^2(1+x)(1-y^2)}{(xy+z)^2}\right)\ge 0$$
or
$$\sum_{cyc}(1-x)\cdot\dfrac{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+xy^2z^2+2xyz-2xz^2-2x^2yz-x^3y^2}{(xy+z)^2}\ge 0.$$
But this way does not help for the starting inequality.

Comment: @Rozenberg Is inequality true for all nonnegatives? Or is there counter-exs ?

Comment: maybe let $y=x+p, z=x+p+q.p,q\ge 0$ is usefull?

Comment: I have a proof for $x+y+z\geq\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: Hint became the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea to prove this inequality is to use the well-know Ky-Fan inequality :

Before that we make the following substitution:

$x=\frac{1}{a}$

$y=\frac{1}{b}$

$z=\frac{1}{c}$

We get the following inequality :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-a)^2}{a^2}\geq \sum_{cyc} \frac{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}$$

Now we have the Ky-fan inequality wich state that for $a,b,c$ belongs to $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$:

$$\frac{(1-a)^2}{a^2}\geq\frac{b^2c^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}\Big(\frac{3-a-b-c}{a+b+c}\Big)^6
$$

So we get this refinement of the starting inequality if we sum each term of the previous inequality:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-a)^2}{a^2}\geq \sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2c^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}\Big(\frac{3-a-b-c}{a+b+c}\Big)^6 \geq\sum_{cyc} \frac{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}$$

So we prove the inequality for $a,b,c$ belongs to $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$

To prove the remainder of the theorem you just have to play with a variable $u$ and remark that we always have for all positive $x,y,z$:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-x)^2}{x^2}\geq u\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-a)^2}{a^2}\geq u\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2c^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}\Big(\frac{3-a-b-c}{a+b+c}\Big)^6\\ \geq u\sum_{cyc} \frac{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}\geq \sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}{(yz+x)^2}$$

We make the following substitution on the first inequality :

$x=\cos^2 s$;
$y=\cos^2 v$;
$z=\cos^2 w$

And

$a=\cos^2 p$;
$b=\cos^2 r$;
$c=\cos^2 q$

With $p,q,r$ belonging to $[\arccos (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}});\arccos(\frac{1}{2})]$ :

We get this :

$$\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 s\geq u\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 p$$

we put :

$$u=\frac{\sum_{cyc}\tan^2 s\tan^2 v}{\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 p}$$

Edit for Martin R :

We have build $u$ exactly to obtain the first inequality :

So we have :

$$u\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 p=\sum_{cyc}\tan^2 s\tan^2 v$$

And

$$\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 s\geq\sum_{cyc}\tan^2 s\tan^2 v$$

And to conclude it's just Am-Gm or $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$

Now we need to prove that $u$ satisfy the last inequality :

With the previous substitution  and combine with the well-know formula $(\cos a^2+\sin a^2)^2=1$ we find:

$$\frac{\sum_{cyc}\tan^2 s\tan v^2}{\sum_{cyc}\tan^4 p}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(\tan^4 p+2\tan^2 p)((\tan^4 r+2\tan^2 r)}{\Big(1+\frac{\cos^2 q}{\cos^2 r\cos^2 p}\Big)^2}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(\tan^4 s+2\tan^2 s)((\tan^4 v+2\tan^2 v)}{\Big(1+\frac{\cos^2 w}{\cos^2 v\cos^2 s}\Big)^2}$$

Comment: Why $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{b^2c^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}\left(\frac{3-a-b-c}{a+b+c}\right)^6 \geq\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}$ is true?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344914/inequality-with-3-variables).It works because there is no order on $a,b,c$.

Comment: Explain please your   play with a variable $u$ for the rest cases.

Comment: If you use logarithmic majorization you will find a particular value for $u$ ;$u=\frac{(1-x)^2a^2}{x^2(1-a)^2}$

Comment: Explain please, how you used it.

Comment: Can someone, which upper voted this post, explain me why this solution is true? I think it's nothing.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to consider $a,b,c$ in $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$? Why does $u=\frac{\sum_{cyc}\tan s^2\tan v^2}{\sum_{cyc}\tan p^4}$ satisfy $\sum_{cyc}\tan s^4\geq u\sum_{cyc}\tan p^4$? Why does the last inequality hold?

Comment: Also note that $\cos s^2$ usually means $\cos (s^2)$, but I assume that you mean $(\cos s)^2 = \cos^2 s$.

Comment: Yes the editor make a mistake but it's nothing . See my edit for your previous questions .

Comment: @FatsWallers: Why is it sufficient to consider $a, b, c$ in $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg is this solution considered complete? I am curious.

Comment: @dezdichado I think it's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

About the source of the inequality: In a blog entry posted in 2013, it was said that this problem was proposed by Dongyi Wei (full marks both at 50th IMO 2009 and 49th IMO 2008) and was solved by Zipei Nie (full marks at 51st IMO 2010).

Some years ago, I gave another proof which is ugly (long).

There are four possible cases:
(1) Exactly two of $a, b, c$ are larger than $1$.
(2) Exactly one of $a, b, c$ is larger than $1$.
(3) All of $a, b, c$ are larger than $1$.
(4) None of $a, b, c$ is larger than $1$, i.e., $0 < a, b, c \le 1$.

**Case** (1): Due to symmetry, assume that $a\ge b > 1\ge c > 0$. It suffices to prove that
$$(a-1)^2 + (b-1)^2 \ge \frac{c^2(a^2-1)(b^2-1)}{(ab+c)^2}
= \frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(ab/c+1)^2}(a-1)(b-1).$$
Since $\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(ab/c+1)^2}
\le \frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(ab+1)^2} < 1$, the inequality is true.

**Case** (2): Due to symmetry, assume that $a > 1 \ge b \ge c > 0$. It suffices to prove that
$$(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2 \ge \frac{a^2(1-b^2)(1-c^2)}{(bc+a)^2}.$$
If $a > 2$, we have $\mathrm{LHS} > 1$.
Clearly $\mathrm{RHS} < 1$. The inequality is true.
If $1 < a \le 2$, it suffices to prove that
$$(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2 \ge \frac{4(1-b^2)(1-c^2)}{(bc+2)^2}
= \frac{4(1+b)(1+c)}{(bc+2)^2}(1-b)(1-c).$$
It suffices to prove that $\frac{4(1+b)(1+c)}{(bc+2)^2} \le 2$.
Since $bc +1 - (b+c) = (b-1)(c-1) \ge 0$, we have 
\begin{align}
(bc+2)^2 - 2(1+b)(1+c)
&= (bc+1)^2+1 - 2(b+c)\\
& \ge (b+c)^2 + 1 - 2(b+c)\\
& = (b+c-1)^2 \ge 0.
\end{align}
The inequality is true.

**Case** (3): Due to symmetry, assume that $a\ge b\ge c > 1$.
Let $a = \frac{1}{a_1}, \ b = \frac{1}{b_1}, \ c = \frac{1}{c_1}$.
We rewrite the inequality as
$$\frac{1}{a_1^2}y_1+\frac{1}{b_1^2}y_2+\frac{1}{c_1^2}y_3
\ge 0$$ where
\begin{align}
y_1 &= (1-a_1)^2 - \frac{a_1^2(1-b_1^2)(1-c_1^2)}{(b_1c_1+a_1)^2}, \\
y_2 &= (1-b_1)^2 -
\frac{b_1^2(1-c_1^2)(1-a_1^2)}{(a_1c_1+b_1)^2}, \\
y_3 &= (1-c_1)^2
- \frac{c_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1-b_1^2)}{(a_1b_1+c_1)^2}.
\end{align}
Let us prove that $y_1 \ge y_2 \ge y_3$.
First, since $0<a_1 \le b_1 \le c_1< 1$ and $b_1c_1/a_1 + 1 \ge a_1c_1/b_1 + 1$,
we have $y_1\ge y_2$. Second, we have
\begin{align}
&\qquad  y_2-y_3 \\
&= (1-b_1)^2 + \frac{c_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1-b_1^2)}{(a_1b_1+c_1)^2}
- \Big[(1-c_1)^2 + \frac{b_1^2(1-c_1^2)(1-a_1^2)}{(a_1c_1+b_1)^2}\Big]\\
&= (1-b_1)\Big[1 - b_1 + \frac{c_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1+b_1)}{(a_1b_1+c_1)^2}\Big]
- (1-c_1)\Big[1 - c_1 + \frac{b_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1+c_1)}{(a_1c_1+b_1)^2}\Big]\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{\ge} (1-c_1)\Big[1 - b_1 + \frac{c_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1+b_1)}{(a_1b_1+c_1)^2}\Big]
- (1-c_1)\Big[1 - c_1 + \frac{b_1^2(1-a_1^2)(1+c_1)}{(a_1c_1+b_1)^2}\Big]\\
&= (1-c_1)(1-a_1^2)
\Big[\frac{c_1-b_1}{1-a_1^2}+ \frac{1+b_1}{(a_1b_1/c_1+1)^2} - \frac{1+c_1}{(a_1c_1/b_1+1)^2}\Big]\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{\ge} (1-c_1)(1-a_1^2)
\Big[\frac{c_1-b_1}{1-a_1^2}+ \frac{1+b_1}{(a_1b_1/c_1+1)^2} - \frac{1+c_1}{(a_1b_1/c_1 + 1)^2}\Big]\\
&= (1-c_1)(1-a_1^2)
\Big[\frac{c_1-b_1}{1-a_1^2}- \frac{c_1-b_1}{(a_1b_1/c_1 + 1)^2}\Big]\\
&\stackrel{(3)}{\ge} 0. 
\end{align}
Here, (1) holds because $1-b_1 \ge 1-c_1 > 0$,
(2) holds because $a_1c_1/b_1 + 1 \ge a_1b_1/c_1 + 1$,
and (3) holds because $1- a_1^2 < (a_1b_1/c_1 + 1)^2$.
Then, since $\frac{1}{a_1^2} \ge \frac{1}{b_1^2} \ge \frac{1}{c_1^2}$ and
$y_1\ge y_2\ge y_3$, according to Chebyshev's sum inequality, we have
$\frac{1}{a_1^2}y_1+\frac{1}{b_1^2}y_2+\frac{1}{c_1^2}y_3
\ge \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\frac{1}{b_1^2}+\frac{1}{c_1^2})(y_1+y_2+y_3)$.
It suffices to prove that $y_1+y_2+y_3\ge 0$. It is true if **Case** (4) is true.

**Case** (4): If the proof of Cases (1)(2)(3) is true, I will give the proof of Case (4).
To Be Continued.

Comment: Let's continue. 

Comment: @youthdoo Thanks. I will rewrite in some days. So I will update it in some days.