# Inequality with 3 variables

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

relatively to my answer in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330511/show-this-inequality?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I have to prove this for $a,b,c$ belonging to $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$ :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1-c^2)(1-b^2)}{(bc+a)^2} \leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{c^2b^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}(\frac{(3-a-b-c)}{a+b+c})^6$$
Edit : I'am going to transform my proof wich is false .
My proof :

We study the following function :

$$f(x)=\frac{(yz+x)^2(y^2)(z^2)}{((1-z)^2(1-y)^2)}(\frac{(3-x-y-z)}{(x+y+z)})^6
-(1-y^2)(1-z^2)$$

The derivative of the function $f(x)$ is :

$$f'(x)=\frac{2z^2y^2(x+y+z-3)^5(x+yz)(x^2+2x(y+z+3)+y^2+y(11z-3)+(z-3)z)}{(y-1)^2(z-1)^2(x+y+z)^7}$$

For $x,y,z$ belonging to $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$ we have:

$$x^2+2x(y+z+3)+y^2+y(11z-3)+(z-3)z>0$$

And

$$(x+y+z-3)^5<0$$

So the function is strictly decreasing for $x$ belonging to  $[\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2}]$

from above arguments we have :

$f(\frac{1}{2})\leq f(x)$

so get the following inequality:

$$\frac{(1-c^2)(1-b^2)}{(bc+(0.5))^2} \leq \frac{c^2b^2}{(1-b)^2(1-c)^2}(\frac{(3-(0.5)-b-c)}{(0.5)+b+c})^6$$

Now we put :

$y=bc$

$x=b+c$

We have to prove with the condition of the beginning :

$$1\leq \frac{(y+0.5)^2}{(1-x^2+2y+y^2)}(\frac{y}{(1-x+y)})^2(\frac{(3-0.5-x)}{(x+0.5)})^6$$

We introduce the following function :

$$g(x)=\frac{(y+0.5)^2}{(1-x^2+2y+y^2)}(\frac{y}{(1-x+y)})^2(\frac{(3-0.5-x)}{(x+0.5)})^6$$

For the same reason we remark the function is decreasing for $x$ belonging to $[\frac{1}{2};1]$

Finaly we introduce a last function $h(y)$ :

$$h(y)=\frac{(y+0.5)^2}{(1-0.5^2+2y+y^2)}(\frac{y}{(1-0.5+y)})^2(\frac{(3-0.5-0.5)}{(0.5+0.5)})^6$$

$\blacksquare$QED.

My question : have you easier ?

Comment: I think there is  mistake in your computations of the derivative. Check it again please.

Comment: If you insert $b=c=1/4$ and take $\frac{1}{4}< a \leq \frac{1}{2} $ you find that the inequality is incorrect. In the proof, for the decreasing function $f(x)$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$ it follows that $f(x) \geq f(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: thanks you for remark this .

Comment: You missed the point, which is that the inequality you are proving is not valid under the constraints on $a,b,c \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Have you a couterexample please ?

Comment: Sure, as mentioned above. Take $b=c=\frac{1}{4}$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$, than the lhs gives $\frac{(15/16)^2}{(9/16)^2}=\frac{25}{9}$ whereas the rhs gives $\frac{(1/4)^4}{(3/4)^4} 2^6 = \frac{64}{81}$, so the lhs > rhs. Hence the inequality given is invalid.

Comment: @ Ronald Blaak With the sum it is correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think that with the added sum over cyclic permutations the inequality is  correct. That is to say I have no proof, but a numerical minimisation procedure did not immediately give a problem.